# Initializing a contour in the mask of an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

**Background:** I have an image which is `width-256 x height-1024` and I am trying to initialize a "contour" for a mask of my image. The mask is of the same dimensions of my image, and all pixel values are set to 0. The actual image is a grayscale image.

I am trying to initialize a contour in the mask based on the first "sufficiently bright" pixel value in each column of the image. That is, for each column, I iterate through all rows, and find the first pixel that exceeds a threshold (say average of all pixel values in image). Once the first "sufficiently bright" pixel is found, I move to the next column, and repeat the process.

**Code:**  This is what I have done so far, and the logic seems right to me. However, I am running into an **infinite loop** every time there is a column in which, all rows don't have a value which exceed the threshold. I break my code as soon as the total number of columns in the image is reached. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
// prior mem_allocation of host_iData and mask
// host_iData contains image data 

int iterate = 0;
int c =0;
int r = 0;
while( c<output.cols ) {
    while( r<output.rows ) {
        int val = host_iData[r*output.cols + c];

        if( val > sum) {
            mask[r*output.cols + c] = 255;
            c++; 
            r = 0;
            itr++; 
        }
        else { r++; }

        if( itr == output.cols) { break; }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"What am I doing wrong?"*

```
while ( c < output.cols ) {
    while ( r < output.rows ) {

        if ( value of pixel is higher than some threshold) {
            start processing the following column starting the first row
        }
        else { 
            process next row
        }
    }
}
```

The condition `r < output.rows` completely destroys this logic. The condition's body keeps on setting `r` to `0` making the first loop infinite. I think what you meant was this:

```
        if ( value of pixel is higher than some threshold) {
            start processing the following column starting the first row
            break; // <-- THIS
        }
```

that would stop the inner loop completely, causing the outer loop continue.

Comment: If I don't set the `r=0`, then I move to the same row in the next column. I don't get the second part of the code you wrote?